# json.decode() throws error 18641 (Map<> problem)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I made s imple app to read JSON data from a file and have two problems with it. The main one is that the `json.decode()` method throws the error 18641 `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'` and I have no idea what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(context)
    {
        getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then(
            (Directory dir)
            {
                File jsonFile = new File(dir.path + "/" + "appstorage.json");
                bool fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
                
                if(fileExists)
                {
                    String fileContentAsString = jsonFile.readAsStringSync();
                    Map<String, String> fileContent = json.decode(fileContentAsString);
                    print(fileContent);
                }
            }
        );

        return Center(child: Text('Hello Flutter!', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr));
    }
}
```

The JSON file contents are:
`"{"1024\t":"TextValue"}"`

And the other problem (should I create a separate post for this?) is that while debuggin step-by-step, I have to step over the line
`File jsonFile = new File(dir.path + "/" + "appstorage.json");`
four times before the program actually advances to the next line. Why is it doing that? I presume it's related to something being done on a separate thread but I don't know what exactly is happening.

Comment: "{"1024\t":"TextValue"}" or {"1024\t":"TextValue"} ?

Comment: The VSCode preview shows `"{"1024\t":"TextValue"}"
`

Comment: Have you tried changing the 2nd type of your `Map` to `dynamic`? `Map<String, dynamic> fileContent`

Comment: I didn't really think of that. Just tried it now and it works! Why though? And also, what about the `File` instantiation line and the step-over being stuck on it for 4 cycles?

Comment: @rickimaru, ok, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Val Glad to hear it solved your problem. `json.decode(...)` does not have type inference that's why you must always set the 2nd type to `dynamic`. As for your `File` instantiation issue, I haven't really tried running your code, so I can't say for sure what's the problem.